# How do you create a DAG with JSON in Apache Apex?

Tags: json, stream-processing, apache-apex

I've been trying to find the documentation for populating a DAG instance using JSON. Is there formal documentation to the format somewhere?

Comment: Did you see https://www.datatorrent.com/blog/tracing-dags-from-specification-to-execution/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON application spec is available under http://apex.apache.org/docs/apex/application_development/#json-file-dag-specification

At the current moment JSON application creation is enabled with dtAssemble, a beta feature of DataTorrent RTS.  The documentation for using dtAssemble to create JSON apps is available under http://docs.datatorrent.com/dtassemble/

You can experiment with dtAssemble, and inspect the PUT operations of `/ws/v2/appPackages/[user]/[package]/[version]/applications/[application]` service call to see the JSON structure generated for the application you're building.  You can also download the application package where the app is being saved, unzip it, and inspect app/*.json files added there.